# How to implement a symfony4 containing multiple project modules?

Tags: php, symfony, domain-driven-design

How to implement a symfony4 containing multiple project modules？
like this！

[image]

Can I use a Bundle?

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles.html

In Symfony versions prior to 4.0, it was recommended to organize your own application code using bundles. This is no longer recommended and bundles should only be used to share code and features between multiple applications.

It is recommended to managed your modules/plugins via composer and use it when convenient in your App/

Comment: Follow the documentation https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/creating-the-project.html 

It is the best place to start with Symfony.